# cannot run prism xamarin with Xamarin.Forms 3.5.0.62956-pre2 or 4.0 pre2

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

been trying to play with the new stuff that will soon coming out from xamarin form

I create a new Prism xamarin app
I upgrade the nuget packages to point to xamarin 3.5 or 4.0
but I cannot get the solution to run.

It just hangs!!

It works when I do the same thing with a standard xamarin form template

I know its just preview but I would like to know if somebody has tried to compile and run any app using prism xamarin and the preview xam forms.

many thanks

Comment: "if somebody has tried to compile and run any app using prism xamarin and the preview xam forms." - No, but i tried freshmvvm and it works like a charm!

Comment: @G.hakim I am using prism so that works on freshmvvm is not good to me. thanks anyway

Comment: Did you check whether or not prism supports latest XF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware there should not be any issues with Prism when targeting Xamarin Forms 3.5+.

That said if you're wanting to target one of the pre-releases I would suggest either installing the current preview on NuGet which targets 4.0-pre1, or the latest CI build which targets 3.5-pre2 and has a number of great new features including a more robust API for IContainerRegistry as well as support for Tuples in INavigationService.

Comment: thank you. I will try again. we are about to start a new app and would be great if I could get working i will get try again a blank project against 4.0 pre1 and  prism preview and see if runs.